# How to configure hibernate on macOS Monterey?

Tags: macos, battery, sleep-wake, monterey, hibernate

For the life of me, I cannot get macOS Monterey to hibernate on my 2015 MacBook Pro on battery power.

Here is my `pmset -g` output while on battery:

```
% pmset -g
System-wide power settings:
Currently in use:
 lidwake              0
 autopoweroff         1
 standbydelayhigh     5
 autopoweroffdelay    1
 proximitywake        0
 standby              1
 standbydelaylow      5
 ttyskeepawake        0
 hibernatemode        25
 powernap             0
 gpuswitch            2
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 highstandbythreshold 50
 displaysleep         1
 sleep                1
 acwake               0
 halfdim              1
 tcpkeepalive         1
 disksleep            10
```

No matter how long I wait, or by using `pmset sleepnow`, this does not hibernate. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How long are you waiting after putting the machine to sleep before waking it up?

Comment: @pion 15 minutes

Comment: Let's look at your power management logs. Do the following: (1) Note the exact time (2) Attempt to place the system into hibernation mode (3) Wait 15 minutes, then wake the system (4) Note the exact time again (5) Run the command `pmset -g log` (6) Copy only the parts of the log that are between the start and end timestamps and add them to your question.

Comment: I never got hibernate working again, after Catalina... My MBP does not hibernate any more and draws power on battery (tried all conceivable pmset settings, logs, support, external application). If you found a solution, please post.

Comment: My `pmset -g` clearly says "sleep prevented by bluetoothd, coreaudiod, powerd, sharingd". And it really won't even sleep while connected to power.