# Deeper sleep when closing lid of MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, sleep-wake, monterey

I have a mid-2015 MacBook Pro (Monterey 12.5.1), and the battery is quite badly degraded, despite being replaced once. I can only just get 30-40 minutes of use from a fully charged battery. This isn't so much a problem, as I rarely use the device without a power source, however I'm finding when I shut the lid of the device at night with a 100% charge, by the following day when I return to the device, the battery will have drained to < 10% and the device powers off, as can be seen in the image below.
[image: Battery loses charge when lid closed and device is sleeping]
My battery settings are shown below.
[image: Battery Settings]
If I shut the device down at night, when I power it back up the following day, the battery has lost no more than a couple of percentage points of charge, so my question is, is it possible to have the Mac go in to a deeper sleep when the lid is shut?

Comment: How many cycles did you get out of the replaced battery?

Comment: Only 106, but it's quite old and the device is used for around 8 hours most days, and it's always plugged in when in use. I stopped leaving it plugged in overnight, as the original batteries swelled up quite dangerously.

Comment: Yes, for the price of a battery you’re quite the way into a M1 mini or discount M1 Air - you’re doing everything right, just going to be hard to justify another swap if you can make the jump to a new Mac. See if you can get a couple hundred trade in and shop refurbished? https://www.apple.com/shop/refurbished/mac

Comment: Thanks, I'm planning on getting a new MBP in the next 12 months or so, so don't really want to spend any more on this if I can help it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ve never been able to get [hibernate to work in a way that was helpful](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/433993/5472), so if you can’t keep it alive by turning off Power Nap (which your screen shot shows is already off), you’ll have to shut it down, plug it in or replace the battery.

- https://support.apple.com/lv-lv/guide/mac-help/mh40773/mac

Comment: Thanks @bmike, I was hoping there was some hidden setting I might not have been aware of that would have caused a deeper sleep, though (unfortunately) I suspect your answer is correct, as ultimately I need to replace the battery. Given the age of my device, it's not economically viable to replace the battery, though I am due an upgrade.